# When using PhoneGap, I have a full web like capabilities?

Tags: facebook, jquery, cordova

I'm studying the best plataform for developing a mobile app (for Android, first) which will have a lot of web interactions, like loading XML, images and interactions with Facebook(loading contacts, for example).

I want know if a app created with PhoneGap can behave like a normal web page(if can use Jquery for Ajax, etc), or I'll have problems doing that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use jQuery and Ajax with PhoneGap.

Comment: And about Facebook interactions?

Comment: Thanks for that link, but I didn't found any Facebook related plugin.

Comment: sorry forgot it was on Dave's repo https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect